# How can I directly the name of a value inside a QML enum?

Tags: qt, enums, qml

Our automated tests have a method which relies on unique strings for UI elements. These strings are maintained inside an enum:

object.qml/

```
QtObject {
    enum Panel1 {
        panel1Button,
    }
    enum Panel2{
        panel2Button,

    }
}
```

The problem is that when referring to these enum values, there is some ambiguity: 
`var objectname: object.Panel1.panel1button` 
and

`var objectname2: object.Panel1.panel2button`

will both return '0'

Is there a way I can return the name of the enum value? QML does not seem to natively support methods like JSON.Stringify or .name()

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: If I could retrieve the name of the UI element, in string format:

"panel1button" 

I'd be much further along

Comment: This sounds like a good time to refactor the system... But let me ask, do you need to get the enum names from QML/JS, or can you use C++? With C++ you may be able to get the `QMetaObject` for the `QtObject` in your example and then get at the `QMetaEnum` info that way (which has a way to convert values to names).  I don't see any way offhand to do it in pure JS.